How to perform forward-fill along 0th dimension of N-D tensor in Tensorflow
For example, take the following tensor:
tf.constant([
  [0,      np.nan, 2, 1],
  [np.nan, 3,      3, 4],
])

I'd like to implement a forward-fill operation like pd.DataFrame.ffill (with axis=0). The output of the ffill operation should therefore be:
[
  [0, np.nan, 2, 1]
  [0, 3,      3, 4]
]

Note that in practice this tensor might have a 3rd batch dimension or further dimensions. It's not clear to me how I can achieve this tensor transformation. I did find the following question that addresses this for the 1D case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52818310/1613983
However, the values variable in that implementation is a sparse representation of the input data, which works fine in one dimension, but I wasn't able to translate that to the 2D (or higher) case.
